# Can Microsoft Graph create Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In a program, I am hoping to use Microsoft Graph to create a Microsoft Team, and then a channel in that team. I read on this forum that creating teams is not yet supported, but the date of the answers do not include the year. Is it correct that it is still not supported? What is the ETA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Microsoft Team for Classes programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624064/create-microsoft-team-for-classes-programmatically)

Comment: Questions without a year are from the current year. The question this duplicates is from just a couple of months ago.

Comment: Thanks, now I know, but they really should include the year all the time since it's not self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is now an API for this - but it looks like a 2 step process - first create a group and then "make it into a Team".

See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/team_put_teams

I also believe that we are working on a single API call to create a Team, but that's not available yet.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi Dan, that is exactly how I am creating Teams right now. Is there any ETA on this API ? I've heard it would be about september ? Will this Teams API contain mgmt of channels / tabs, mgmt of owners/members/externals ... ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Team creation API is now out of beta [GA API to create Team using Group](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/team_put_teams)

Group has to be created before the Team as per this API